# Partial deserialization of a huge binary file - Java

Tags: java, serialization

This is my first question to StackOverflow. Please let me know if the question is not clear and need any more details.

I have a class which has three attributes like this:

```
 class SampleClass {
long [] field1;
float[] field2;
float[] field3;
}
```

A huge SampleClass object is built(with about a billion entries for each array). This object is serialized in one host and the serialized file is uploaded to another machine. Now I want to deserialize only a portion of the file so that I can get a smaller SampleClass object with about 10 indices filled for each field and not the complete object. Because this machine does not have enough capacity to load such a huge object in memory. Is this possible?

The object is serialized using JAVA's writeObject method and it is done by a different utility and so I have no control over it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should this object not be stored in database rather then in binary file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget using the Java serialization API - it's only designed to deserialize everything. If you have no control over how the serialized file is generated, then you should consider *parsing* the serialized file yourself and extracting the necessary parts - it's not really that hard.

The Java serialization format is well-documented (see e.g. [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), [informative article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html)), and tools exist to parse the format (e.g. [Serialysis](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2007/06/disassembling_s.html), [jdeserialize](https://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize/)) though it isn't particularly hard to write your own tool based on the format spec.

Once you can parse the serialized data, you can simply extract what you need and skip over what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to actually serialize only the portion you need, given that you cannot control/override serialization itself. On the machine which serialized entire file and is able to deserialize it:

1) load entire file into object

2) create new object of SampleClass

3) copy elements from required region in each array to blank SampleClass object

4) serialize this smaller version

If it helps any, fields can be made transient so they will not be serialized.

Still, it looks to me that this object should be in database:

- It does not fit virtual memory
- only portion of it is required at given time.

So you could use hard disk to store it and queries to get required portions.