# How to identify a specific object byte offset value and extract it directly from a serialized binary file?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, extract, offset

I have the following:

```
public class Building implements Serializable {
    int buildingID;
    String buildingName;
    List<Person> personList;

    ...
}
class Person implements Serializable {
    int age;
    String name;
    byte[] importantData;

    ...
}
```

I'm planning to serialize Building as a binary file. We can assume that personList will hold numerous Person entries (3GB+). In the future, I plan to use an existing Building file to extract a specific importantData from a specific Person entry in personList. Currently, the most straightforward way for me to do this would be to deserialize the file back to Building object to get the specific importantData. However, since this Building file is pretty big, the deserializing process will take some time.

I would like to do this in a much faster way by simply reading the data directly from the serialized file (skipping deserialization). The problem is that I'm not exactly sure how I can obtain or learn the byte offset value where importantData is actually stored in the file. Additionally, is it possible to get this offset value without running a byte comparison on the serialized Building file itself?

Comment: You can't with Java Object Serialization. It is an, err, serial format. No random access.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestions

1. Don't use java serialization and plain file system to manage large datasets
2. It always better to use a dedicated data store to manage data across multiple service instances
3. Use some kind of columnar data store as you have requirement to fetch specific parts of record
4. Data consistency can be improved by using shared data store (still not guaranteed and depends on application logic and data store support)
5. Java serialization can make it difficult to change the structure of data in future
6. If serialization is the only option, then look into kryo or proto based serialization

Comment: I am currently using serialization for a specific reason. While I realize that using other data store is another solution to my problem, I would like to know if there is an answer to the question that I posted.

Comment: @athamrin Please check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931106/partial-deserialization-of-a-huge-binary-file-java)

Comment: If possible, try to separate serialization of `importantData` and other fields to separate files.